# Different signature for each elliptic curve signature generation

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, elliptic-curve

I am using elliptic curve for generating signature. The issue is it generates a different signature every time with the same key pair. I tried the Bouncy Castle libraries as well as [`ECDsa`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa(v=vs.110).aspx). The signature get verified with both, but I want the same signature every time I use the same key pair.

What could possibly do to generate the same signature every time? Or is this not possible using elliptic curve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, standard DSA is non-deterministic, which for ECDSA means that it relies on a cryptographically secure random number generator ([in step 3 in the description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm), to be precise).

If a constant is used with different input then ECDSA will *leak the private key*. This is what happened to the Sony private key used to sign games, [which was cracked by the German Chaos Computer Club](https://events.ccc.de/congress/2010/Fahrplan/attachments/1780_27c3_console_hacking_2010.pdf) (but only at page 122!). Of course, ECDSA cannot tell if the same data is used or not.

There is a deterministic way of generating ECDSA signatures specified in [RFC 6979, "    Deterministic Usage of the Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) and Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979).

You can do this using the following Bouncy Castle code in C#:

```
ECDsaSigner signer = new ECDsaSigner(new HMacDsaKCalculator(new Sha256Digest()));
```

which apparently is used for blockchain technology such as bitcoin.